# In R ggplot,what's the usage of `..density..`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
iris %>% 
ggplot(.,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=..density..,fill=Species))+
  scale_x_continuous(limit=c(0,10),breaks =seq(0,10,1))+
  geom_density(alpha=.2)
```

Above script works well,but I never seen `..density..` in R.
What's `..density..`?

Comment: It's quite old syntax that has been replaced by `after_stat(density)` in ggplot2 v3.3.0 and went through an in between phase with `stat(density)`, which is explained in the details of `?after_stat`. It just means that it is a calculated variable from the stat part of a layer. You can see these documented at stat manual pages under 'computed variables' in e.g. `?stat_density`

Comment: In this particular case, `..density..` (or in current ggplot `after_stat(density)`) isn't necessary. You can remove it and the plot will still work because `geom_density` is already automatically internally computing the density and placing it in the `y` aesthetic. The `.` (in `ggplot(., aes(`) also isn't necessary and can be removed, because the pipe automatically pipes the data frame into the first argument of `ggplot`. So all you need is: `iris %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) + ...`

Comment: There's a short description of many of the `..var..` special symbols on the [cheat sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf). One of the most useful, but poorly documented ones is `..PANEL..`.

Comment: @IanCampbell huh? Never came across ..PANEL.. what does it do??

Comment: @Tjebo It indicates which panel of a `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As teunbrand said,`..` is replaced by `after_stat`.

> after_stat() replaces the old approaches of using either stat() or
>   surrounding the variable names with ...